# For arbitrary metric spaces, if $\sup E\not\in E$, then must $\sup E$ be a limit point of $E$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Let $E\subset\mathbf R$, and suppose that $\sup E$ exists in $\mathbf R$. It is not too difficult to prove that if $\sup E\not\in E$, then $\sup E$ is a limit point of $E$:

> Let $\alpha=\sup E$, and suppose that $\alpha$ is *not* a limit point of $E$. Then there is a $h>0$ such that $(\alpha-h,\alpha+h)$ does not contain any members of $E$. Hence every member of $E$ must be less than or equal to $\alpha-h$. But this contradicts the fact that $\alpha$ is the least upper bound of $E$.

My question is: can this proof be generalised? More explicitly, suppose that $X$ is both an ordered set and a metric space, and let $E\subset X$. Assuming that $\sup E$ exists in $X$, must it be the case that if $\sup E\not\in E$, then $\sup E$ is a limit point of $E$? In case the answer is negative, is there an extra condition which *does* guarantee this property?

Comment: Do you assume any relation between the metric and the order?

Comment: @MartinR: No. But now I worry that this renders my question trivial.

Comment: Normally you would want to assume that X is equipped with the [order topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology).  In that setting it is true that $\sup E$ is either contained in $E$ or is a limit point of $E$, and the proof is basically identical to the one you already gave.  You don't need the metric structure if you are willing to work in a general topological space.

Comment: A general fact for spaces in the order topology: if $\sup E$ exists for some $E \subseteq (X,<)$ then $\sup E \in \overline{E}$. It follows from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is quite trivially negative when the order and metric are unrelated, but it is also negative in a suitably good setup, like subspace of order topology.

Consider $X=[0,1)\cup \{2\}$ and $E=[0,1)$ with the Euclidean metric and order. Note that $2$ is the supremum of $E$ but it is not its limit point. This space however is only a subspace of order topology. It is not the order topology for the inherited order (that would be homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ interval).

In general it is true for order topology over total order. In that situation let $s=\sup E\not\in E$. Then for any $x\in E$ there is $y\in E$ such that $x<y<s$. Therefore every open neighbourhood of $s$ contains some element from $E$ and so it is a limit point of $E$.

If the partial order is not total then again there are counterexamples, even for order topology. For example consider $X=\{0,1,2\}$ with $0<2$ and $1<2$, while $0$ and $1$ are unrelated. The induced order topology has only two (nontrivial) open subsets: $\{0,1\}$ and $\{2\}$. So $E=\{0,1\}$ has $2$ as the supremum but it is not its limit point.